# How to create JavaDoc using Android Studio without R and BuildConfig?

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

I want to generate the JavaDoc for my library excluding R and BuildConfig. The `Generate JavaDoc...` functionality from the `Tools` menu does not have the option to exclude files.

How to create JavaDoc using Android Studio without R and and BuildConfig?

Comment: What's even R ...?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

RocketSpock's answer is almost there, but not quite (as of this writing). I can't comment yet, so I'll describe the process I used to exclude `R.java` and `BuildConfig.java` from my Android library's Javadoc in Android Studio 1.2.2. There's basically an extra dialog that will come in very handy:

1. Open menu option `Tools --> Javadoc`.
2. Select `Custom scope`. It's not necessary to select anything from
       the drop-down menu yet.
3. Click the `...` icon to open the `Scopes` dialog.
4. Add a new custom scope with the green `+` icon. Give it a
       descriptive name if you wish.
5. In `Production Classes` (not `Library Classes`, since those are
       imports) navigate to the module(s) you wish to generate Javadoc for,
       and select any individual Java files you wish to include.  In your
       case, you probably want to select an entire module but
       manually exclude `R.java` and `BuildConfig.java`. When you're done, Click `OK` to exit the Scopes dialog.
6. In the `Specify Generate JavaDoc scope` dialog, if your new scope is
   not selected in the `Custom scope` dropdown menu, select it now, as
   well as any other additional options including output directory.
7. Finally, click `OK` to generate your Javadoc.

[image]

Comment: how should i create .jar file for java doc.

Comment: For some reson my Android Studio only shows Admin's folder strucure (not logged in as admin) when selecting ouput folder

Comment: How do I exclude R file?

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer is quite complex and I have a better one.

1. Open menu option Tools --> Javadoc.
2. Select Custom scope. Then select `Project Files`
3. Click `OK`.

[image]

After these you will see the R files and BuildConfig are excluded.

Comment: Thanks for the most simple way, provided with illustrations!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to exclude the generated files (R, BuildConfig, etc.) then you can specify a custom scope for the JavaDoc generation.  For this to correctly work you will need to:

1. In the Project view on the left, select the root source directory to generate the docs for (e.g. "com" or "org")
2. Open the JavaDoc generation dialog (Tools -> Generate JavaDoc...)
3. Select "Custom scope" (it's the 5th radio button in my version) and select your module (e.g. "Module 'library'")
4. Select your other properties such as output directory, method visibility, etc. and click "OK"

That's it.  Your JavaDocs should be generated without the R or BuildConfig files included.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to 
1- go Tools --> Generate JavaDoc... 
2- select Custom scope 
3- from the drop down menu select Open Files.

this method will generate documentation for only the opened files in ur window